# How do I check if WebClient download is completed before I execute a function?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, webclient

I am trying to get to JSON files from different URLs.  How do I make sure both files are downloaded completely before I try to execute something else.

My code looks something like this:

```
WebClient Url1 = new WebClient();
Url1.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Url1_DownloadStringCompleted);
Url1.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"));
WebClient Url2 = new WebClient();
Url2.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Url2_DownloadStringCompleted);
Url2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://anotherexample.com"));

DoSomethingWithJson();

void Url1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null) 
        return;
    json1 = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
}

void Url2_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null) 
        return;
    json2 = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
}
```

Right now, what happens is json1 and json2 returns null values whenever I try to display them in a MessageBox inside DoSomethingWithJson(), and I am assuming this might be because they haven't been downloaded completely.

Comment: Cant you just DoSomethingWithJson(); at the end of both DownloadCompleted events and just return early if either json1 or json2 are null at the start of the function?

Comment: Hi, what I want to happen is that BOTH JSON files are downloaded completely before I execute DoSomethingWithJson()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DownloadStringAsync()` method is returning before the string is downloaded because it's an asynchronous method. If you move the `DoSomethingWithJson()` method to your completed handlers then it will be called once the request is completed. You may want to add logic to the `DoSomethingWithJson()` method so that it only does it's work if all the variables it needs are populated (If indeed you need them all to be populated before you start doing anything else).

```
WebClient Url1 = new WebClient();
Url1.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Url1_DownloadStringCompleted);
Url1.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"));
WebClient Url2 = new WebClient();
Url2.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Url2_DownloadStringCompleted);
Url2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://anotherexample.com"));
var json1Done = false;
var json2Done = false;


void Url1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null) 
        return;
    json1 = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
    json1Done = true;
    if(json1Done && json2Done)
    {
        DoSomethingWithJson();
    }
}

void Url2_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null) 
        return;
    json2 = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
    json2Done = true;
    if(json1Done && json2Done)
    {
        DoSomethingWithJson();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using .Net 4.5 then you could use the new async/await features:

```
WebClient Url1 = new WebClient();
var json1Task = Url1.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"));
WebClient Url2 = new WebClient();
var json2Task = Url2.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://anotherexample.com"));

json1 = await json1Task;
json2 = await json2Task;

DoSomethingWithJson();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm doing a Windows Phone 7.x app.  What I want to happen is that BOTH JSON files are downloaded completely before I execute DoSomethingWithJson()

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice the WinPhone7. I've edited my post. The first code block should do what you need. It uses 2 variables to track whether json1 and json2 are done. In the completed events the done variables are set and when both are set `DoSomethingWithJson();` is called. You could also just call `DoSomethingWithJson();` in both completed handlers regardless and have a check in that method to determine if the json variables are ready for use. If you always expect there to be content you could just do `if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json1) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json2))`

Comment: The edit worked.  Thanks!  Now, if I can find a way to combine those two JSON with different formats.